# How to bind an Angular's controller function using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in AngularJS to programmatically bind a controller method using only javascript(instead of using `ng-*` markup)?

Something like

```
$("#foo").click(FooController.foo)
```

PS: I don't have access to `$compile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need controller's methods or scope's?

in case if you need scope's you can use `angular.element('#myid').scope().method`

But please keep in mind that any modification of scope's values are not detected if you do them outside of AngularJS event processing, so you need to wrap your code into $apply function of scope.

Also keep in mind that in AngularJS DOM modifications from JS are generally "big no no"

Ofcourse there are controller's functions (created using "this.xxx = function () .."). I am not sure that it is good to access them as they are kind of private, but you should be able to access same way: element(..).controller().method

Answer (score 2):

It is not officially supported. For sure it is technically possible with some hacks but binding event handlers from JavaScript would mean getting access to a DOM element from a controller and it goes against principles of AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @Valentyn's answer somewhat, if you had wanted to access a controller method (and not a $scope method) -- e.g., a method defined with `this` in the controller constructor function (on the Angular homepage, the "tabs" directive defines function "addPane" on the controller using `this`) -- you can use

```
angular.element('#myid').controller().method()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you shouldn't. You'll likely run into trouble down the road.

If you can give a bit more explanation as to why you want to do this, there might be a better (and easier) method.